# Looking for problems which can be solved by the similar technique

Tags: elementary-number-theory, problem-solving, big-list

While browsing on internet for different proofs of [Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares), I came across [Zagier's "one-sentence proof"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares#Zagier.27s_.22one-sentence_proof.22) which seems to be the most elegant and short proof. It invokes a proof technique, I am not familiar with. So I would like to see different applications of this proof technique.

Are  there  theorems/problems besides Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares which can be solved using the similar technique.

PS: Please mention a suitable hint for the problem you pose. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what technique does it use?

Comment: @dREaM he defines an involution on the set $S= \lbrace (x,y,z) \in N^3: x^2+4yz=p \rbrace $ and shows that it has one fixed point.This shows that the involution that swaps $y$ and $z$ has a fixed point too, implying the theorem.